# Usando Pandas, ¿cómo puedo extraer de una columna la palabra que coincide con una lista?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un DataFrame como el siguiente, pretendo extraer de la columna Título una parte si esta coincide con una lista y colocar el resultado en otra columna.

La lista estaría comprendida con cadenas como la siguiente:
mi_lista = ['Automata', 'Pearls', 'Deep learning', 'Patterns']

| Título | Autor |
| --- | --- |
| Introduction to Automata Theory | John E. Hopcroft |
| Programming Pearls | Jon L. Bentley |
| Deep Learning | Ian Goodfellow |
| Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture | Martin Fowler |
| Deep Learning with Python | John E. Hopcroft |
| Theory Of Self Reproducing Automata | Jon L. Bentley |
| Enterprise Integration Patterns | Ian Goodfellow |
| Deep Learning: A Practitioner's Approach | Martin Fowler |

Y de esto resulta en una nueva columna en el DataFrame como la siguiente:

| Título | Lista | Autor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Introduction to Automata Theory | Automata | John E. Hopcroft |
| Programming Pearls | Pearls | Jon L. Bentley |
| Deep Learning | Deep Learning | Ian Goodfellow |
| Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture | Patterns | Martin Fowler |
| Deep Learning with Python | Deep Learning | John E. Hopcroft |
| Theory Of Self Reproducing Automata | Automata | Jon L. Bentley |
| Enterprise Integration Patterns | Patterns | John E. Hopcroft |
| Deep Learning: A Practitioner's Approach | Deep Learning | Martin Fowler |

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: La verdad es que nada, estoy muy perdido en ello y no he intentado nada.

Comment: lo ideal es que investigues y experimentes por tu cuenta y si te atascas realizas tu pregunta aquí.  En StackOverflow ayudamos a los demás a resolver sus problemas con el código. Te podría dar una respuesta altamente detallada, pero sigo creyendo que la mejor forma de aprender es experimentando por tu propia cuenta

Comment: Para que tengas más claro como hacer una pregunta puedes leer [ask]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

mi_lista = ['Automata', 'Pearls', 'Deep learning', 'Patterns']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Titulo':['Introduction to Automata Theory', 'Programming Pearls'],
    'Author': ['John E. Hopcroft', 'Jon L. Bentley']
})

df.insert(1, "Lista", df['Titulo'].apply(lambda a: ','.join([l for l in mi_lista if l in a.split()])), True)
print(df)
```

Comment: el usuario no ha intentado nada y deja en claro que no sabe demasiado. Esta respuesta no ayuda ni al usuario que pregunto ni a otros con problemas similares. Revisa [answer] para que sepas como responder.

Comment: Fijate que conozco Python bastante bien, pero de Pandas, nada. Tu respuesta me es totalmente incomprensible, un jeroglífico impenetrable. Hace falta una explicación, un desglose de cada cosa, que hace, como se usa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, gmork, fue muy útil tu solución, tuve algunos detalles, por ejemplo que me da dos respuestas cuando en su caso se da que más de una de las palabras de la lista está contenido dentro de las cadenas de la columna de origen, pero lo resolví encerrando la comprensión de listas en la función set():

` python
df.insert(1, "Lista", df['Titulo'].apply(lambda a: ','.join(set([l for l in mi_lista if l in a.split()]))), True)
`

Ahora solo tengo un detalle, resulta que si en el objeto de la lista se encuentra al final de la cadena de la columna origen, este no lo imprime.

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).